# Using FriendlyId inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, friendly-url, friendly-id

I'm using FriendlyId across many of my models. I noticed some redundancy in my code as far as creating functionality for updating urls so I decided to put it in a module:

```
module TestModule
  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
  end
end
```

The problem now is if I take the essential line of code needed to create the slugs out of my classes and into my module

```
extend FriendlyId; friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `relation' for class `Module'
```

Is there any way to get this to work without me having to right the extend declaration for every one of my models?

Comment: are you including this test module in each class?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately still getting an error.

Comment: and you want your module to extend the friendlyid for the classes it's included in correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The goal is to put the `should_generate_new_friendly_id` method and `extend FriendlyId; friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` in the module which would allow me to just `include TestModule` in the classes I need it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let your module extend the friendly for the classes you include it in.

```
module TestModule
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend FriendlyId
    klass.class_eval do
      friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
    end
    include InstanceMethods
  end
  module InstanceMethods
    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      name_changed?
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model you'll just include this

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TestModule
  # the rest of the class
end
```

Also you could do it without the extra module

```
module TestModule
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend FriendlyId
    klass.class_eval do
      friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
      def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        name_changed?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the argument `class` permitted or is that just a design quirk?

Comment: i can't name the argument `class` but it does refer to the class that included this module

Comment: Still getting `undefined method 'friendly_id' for TestModule:Module`

Comment: i just noticed that those are 2 lines with a semicolon, the second part is run in the wrong context, hold on ill fix it

Comment: try using `klass.friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` instead of just `friendly_id ...`

Comment: With that I got `private method 'include' called for #<Class:0x007fe36ff2a940>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73483/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-carl-edwards).